# A question on Hasudorff Metric, when the subset of the given metric space is compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We have a metric space $(X,d)$ and $Y \subset X$, then the *Hausdorff Metric* is defined as the following: $$d(x,Y)=\inf_{y \in Y}d(x,y), \ \ x \in X$$

I have to show that if $Y$ is compact, then $d(x,Y)=\min_{y \in Y}d(x,y), \ \ x \in X$ i.e. the infimum is attained at some $y \in Y$.

I'm having trouble understanding how to proceed, any hints will be appreciated!

**Edit:**
(Thanks to the comments on this question, I have edited my answer)

Let's have $D_x := \{d(x,y):y\in Y\}$
$$d_x:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ y \mapsto d(x,y)$$

Both are topological spaces apropos their induced topology, and the map satisfies the sequential definition of continuity i.e. consider a converging sequence in $Y$, say $y_n \rightarrow y$, then clearly $d(x,y_n) \rightarrow d(x,y)$. Since we have the fact that continuous image of a compact set is compact, we have $D_x = d_x(Y)$ as compact in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence closed and bounded. Therefore, it attains it's infimum (and supremum).

Comment: A compact set in a metric space is closed.

Comment: Sure, does that mean that $\{d(x,y) : y \in Y \}$ is closed too?

Comment: You mean a set of the form $\{y\in Y: d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}$ for some given $\varepsilon>0$? This is set can be shown to be closed.

Comment: I don't follow. I've edited my question with an attempt of my own. Could you comment on it's validity?

Comment: That's perfectly valid. If I had one quibble, it would be the word "surjective". If you're looking at $\mathbb{R}$ being the codomain, the map is not surjective. Fortunately, surjectivity is not needed - the continuous image of a compact set is compact, surjective or not.

Comment: Your attempt is actually correct. Note that you don't need to use the sequential continuity, in fact it's not too hard to show that the map $d_x$ is Lipschitz (it's basically just the triangle inequality).

Comment: The argument seems to be correct. Not sure you need this surjectivity argument. As pointed for each $x$ the function $d(x,y)$ is a continuous function from the compact set $Y$ into the nonnegative reals. Hence by Weierstrass $d(x,\cdot)$ attains both its minimum and maximum on $Y$.

Comment: I also have a quibble with the question itself. I know the Hausdorff metric as a metric on the non-empty, closed, bounded subsets of a metric space. Given a metric space $(X, d)$, and such subsets $A, B \subseteq X$, the Hausdorff metric is given by$$\mathcal{H}(A, B) = \max \left\lbrace \sup_{b \in B} d(b, A), \sup_{a \in A} d(a, B) \right\rbrace.$$

Comment: Ah, yes. My professor made the distinction of calling the definition I put forth in the question as the Hausdorff Metric, and the one that you put forth (and which appears later in my notes) as Hausdorff Distance.

Comment: It's interesting, because the I think of $d(x, Y)$ as a *distance* from a point $x$ to a set $Y$, and $\mathcal{H}$ is, quite literally, a metric, on the set of closed, bounded, non-empty subsets of $X$.

Comment: Yeah, the same thought crossed my mind, a very valid point. I will put forward this definition challenge to my professor.